# Trying to call a sub on another part but it won't accept the parameters

Tags: vb.net

this may be a stupid question but I have a sub that I wanna call on another part of the program. The sub compares what the user types with a list of string already existing in a text file

```
Sub textbox_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    ' Do nothing if the user has clicked the form close button
    LoadAlreadyUsed(dataFile)
    If ActiveControl.Equals(sender) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim txt = GameID.Text

    If Not txt = "" Then
        If Not txt = "message" Then 'checks if the tb is empty/
            Dim res As String = Trim(txt)        'removes spaces from tb/
            txt = res
            textbox.Text = res
            
            If alreadyUsed.Contains(text, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then     'checks if text has already been used/
                MessageBox.Show("error",  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                text.BackColor = Color.Red
                text.Select()
            Else
                text.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
                alreadyUsed.Add(text)
                File.WriteAllLines(dataFile, alreadyUsed.ToArray)   'writes list to txt/
            End If
        End If
        If alreadyUsed.Count > 300 Then
            Do Until alreadyUsed.Count = 300
                alreadyUsed.RemoveAt(15)   'clears textfile if > 300, keeps 300 values /
            Loop
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What I try to do is call this on another button click on the sub that handles button click but I get the error: arg not specified for parameter for sender and e.

Code to call the sub:

```
Private Sub button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button.Click

'/other textbox manipulation stuff/

    if first click = true then

    '-here is where I try to call the previous sub-

        textbox_validating(textbox.text , e)
```

Comment: Show the code that calls it/

Comment: The Sub is expecting an Object and CancelEventArgs. Well, textbox.text is a String which is an Object but in the code of the Sub sender is being cast to a TextBox and a String is not a TextBox. You are passing e for the second parameter. e is System.EventArgs which is not the same as CancelEventArgs.

Comment: It is bad practice to call an event procedure. If you want to run the code, move it to a new sub and call it from both the event procedure and the other code.

Comment: I understand, thank you.
I managed to make it run by calling it like this:
textbox_Validating(Nothing, Nothing) as parameters.

Comment: Don't name a TextBox textbox. You have variables named text and txt. Please use more descriptive names.

Comment: They do have a different name, for the shake of simplicity to make it easier for the question to know what is what I renamed them. But you are right with the names in general.